# Neo4j+Python+PDFMiner

Tags: python

**Здравствуйте. Подскажите как можно выполнить такую задачу:**

На некотором сайте есть документы в формате *pdf*. Много документов.

Нужно взять "конкретные" части из каждого документа (например, пункты 7.2 в каждом документе), т.е. распарсить, вытащить. И построить граф, где будут изображены связи.

Использовать желательно *Python*. Мне подсказали, что это можно сделать с помощью *Neo4j*, а анализировать, парсить *pdf* с помощью *PDFMiner*.

**Спасибо заранее**

Comment: Здравствуй, user! Добро пожаловать на русский StackOverflow! И хочу предупредить заранее, что никто за Вас делать не собирается. Покажите, как Вы пытались сами сделать?